# Retain scroll position on route change in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sample app: http://angular.github.com/angular-phonecat/step-11/app/#/phones

If you choose the last phone "Motorola charm" it will show you the details of the phone. 
When you navigate back with on your browser it reloads the data and scrolling is at the top.

What is the best way to automatically scroll to where is was left when navigatin back?
And also, why does angular reloads the data?

I have the same "angular-phonecat" sample on my computer and I have added an infinite scroll which loads more data as you scroll. So I really dont want the user to reload 50+ items again or scrolling down for 30 seconds.

Comment: Hi, do you happen to have a good resource on how to learn how to implement infinite scroll in angular? Also, did the scroll position stuff work out well?

Comment: I just found this too
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/E4xIDsjIm_k

Comment: Check out [ngInfiniteScroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't used it before, but angular has a [$anchorScroll](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24anchorScroll) service. As to reloading the data, you could cache it using [$cacheFactory](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24cacheFactory), or store the data on a higher scope.

Answer (score 31):

I have a fiddle here that shows how to restore scroll position in the list view after a detail view; not encapsulated in a directive yet, working on that...

http://jsfiddle.net/BkXyQ/6/

```
$scope.scrollPos = {}; // scroll position of each view

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($scope.okSaveScroll) { // false between $routeChangeStart and $routeChangeSuccess
        $scope.scrollPos[$location.path()] = $(window).scrollTop();
        //console.log($scope.scrollPos);
    }
});

$scope.scrollClear = function(path) {
    $scope.scrollPos[path] = 0;
}

$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
    $scope.okSaveScroll = false;
});

$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    $timeout(function() { // wait for DOM, then restore scroll position
        $(window).scrollTop($scope.scrollPos[$location.path()] ? $scope.scrollPos[$location.path()] : 0);
        $scope.okSaveScroll = true;
    }, 0);
});
```

The fiddle also shows fetching the list once, outside of 'ListCtrl'.

Comment: Exactly the one that I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever end up encapsulating this in a directive?

Comment: I have something similar but find there is a flicker when the page scrolls to the top, then we scroll it back to the bottom. Have you found a way to avoid this?

Comment: @JPOD please see my answer for a directive for this code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107531/retain-scroll-position-on-route-change-in-angularjs/26244891#26244891

Comment: Angular apps should use $window instead of $(window) because Angular apps are not supposed use jQuery (except of built-int lite version).

Answer (score 17):

Below is another version of keep-scroll-pos directive. This version

- Remembers scroll position of each *templateUrl* of your $routeProvider definition.
- Respects hash tags, e.g., #/home#*section-2*, will scroll to *#section-2* not previous scroll position.
- Is easy to use, as it is self-contained, and stores scroll positions internally.

Example of html use:

```
<div ng-view keep-scroll-pos></div>
```

The code for keepScrollPos directive is below:

```
"use strict";

angular.module("myApp.directives", [])

.directive("keepScrollPos", function($route, $window, $timeout, $location, $anchorScroll) {

    // cache scroll position of each route's templateUrl
    var scrollPosCache = {};

    // compile function
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
            // store scroll position for the current view
            if ($route.current) {
                scrollPosCache[$route.current.loadedTemplateUrl] = [ $window.pageXOffset, $window.pageYOffset ];
            }
        });

        scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
            // if hash is specified explicitly, it trumps previously stored scroll position
            if ($location.hash()) {
                $anchorScroll();

            // else get previous scroll position; if none, scroll to the top of the page
            } else {
                var prevScrollPos = scrollPosCache[$route.current.loadedTemplateUrl] || [ 0, 0 ];
                $timeout(function() {
                    $window.scrollTo(prevScrollPos[0], prevScrollPos[1]);
                }, 0);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

To disregard previously stored scroll position, and to force to scroll to the top, use pseudo hash tag: *#top*, e.g., href="*#/home#top*".

Alternatively, if you prefer to just always scroll to the top, use built-in ng-view *autoscroll* option:

```
<div ng-view autoscroll></div>
```

Comment: This solution worked best for me. I use ui router for routing and so I replaced all occurrences of $route with $state. Otherwise, no other changes were needed. I also like how $window and $anchorScroll are used instead of the jquery dependent $(window) that is used in some of the other proposed answers.

Answer (score 9):

I have used the solution of @Joseph Oster in order to create a directive.
I have also taken the liberty to update the answer to use:

- $locationChangeStart
- $locationChangeSuccess

as the other events are obsolete.

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/empie/p5pn3rvL/

Directive source:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute'])
    .directive('autoScroll', function ($document, $timeout, $location) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.okSaveScroll = true;

            scope.scrollPos = {};

            $document.bind('scroll', function () {
                if (scope.okSaveScroll) {
                    scope.scrollPos[$location.path()] = $(window).scrollTop();
                }
            });

            scope.scrollClear = function (path) {
                scope.scrollPos[path] = 0;
            };

            scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (route) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $(window).scrollTop(scope.scrollPos[$location.path()] ? scope.scrollPos[$location.path()] : 0);
                    scope.okSaveScroll = true;
                }, 0);
            });

            scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
                scope.okSaveScroll = false;
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: good directive, but I would like to know whether it can be used in ui router?

Comment: this solution doesn't work if the controller/route is changed

Comment: it works fine on the fiddle... what do you expect to see, what are you trying?

Comment: @hariszaman maybe you hit one of the limitations of this very good but succinct solution. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35353316/2518317). Although if it's not working due to you using using ui-router you may have to swap out the calls to `$routeChangeX` to the equivalents

Comment: If the fiddle doesn't show the friends list or table, it might be because your browser is blocking the call to the angular-route JS file over HTTP when fiddle is HTTPS. Just delete the angular-route.js 'external resource' and add it back with a HTTPS prefix.

Answer (score 5):

i created a directive that works on the window scroll ( it could updated to work on any element though )

html usage

```
<div ng-keep-scroll="service.scrollY">
<!-- list of scrolling things here -->
</div>
```

where "service.scrollY" MUST be a variable within a service. Services retain their state and values, controllers are recreated every time they load and clear their values so you cant use them to store persistent data. the controller has a scope variable pointing to the service.

directive js

```
app.directive('ngKeepScroll', function ($timeout) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {

        //load scroll position after everything has rendered
        $timeout(function () {
            var scrollY = parseInt(scope.$eval(attrs.ngKeepScroll));
            $(window).scrollTop(scrollY ? scrollY : 0);
        }, 0);

        //save scroll position on change
        scope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function () {
            scope.$eval(attrs.ngKeepScroll + " = " + $(window).scrollTop());
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Example of a service: 
mod.factory("CacheService", function($cacheFactory) { return { data:{ scrollY: 0 } }; });
then in controller: $scope.service = CacheService.data

Answer (score 3):

Based on the great answer from br2000, I updated the directive code to work with ui-router. For states with same name but different params I serialize the $state.params object to make up a unique key in the `scrollPosCache` object.

```
.directive("keepScrollPos", function($state, $window, $timeout, $location, $anchorScroll) {

    // cache scroll position of each route's templateUrl
    var scrollPosCache = {};

    // compile function
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {

      scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
        // store scroll position for the current view
        if ($state.current.name) {
          scrollPosCache[$state.current.name + JSON.stringify($state.params)] = [ $window.pageXOffset, $window.pageYOffset ];
        }
      });

      scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
        // if hash is specified explicitly, it trumps previously stored scroll position
        if ($location.hash()) {
          $anchorScroll();

          // else get previous scroll position; if none, scroll to the top of the page
        } else {
          var prevScrollPos = scrollPosCache[$state.current.name + JSON.stringify($state.params)] || [ 0, 0 ];
          $timeout(function() {
            $window.scrollTo(prevScrollPos[0], prevScrollPos[1]);
          }, 0);
        }
      });
    }
  })
```

Comment: your needs may necessitate removing the param caching in the scrollPosCache here, if all you care about is the current state.

Answer (score 1):

If your page requires fetching of data to display, you may have to use $routeChangeSuccess and delay the scrolling function call.

```
    scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function() {
        $timeout(function () {
            var scrollY = parseInt(scope.$eval(attrs.ngKeepScroll));
            $(window).scrollTop(scrollY ? scrollY : 0);
        }, 1000); // delay by 1 sec
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a version that works with any overflowed element, not just the document body:

```
.directive("keepScrollPos", function($route, $timeout, $location, $anchorScroll) {

  // cache scroll position of each route's templateUrl
  var cache = {};

  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    link: function($scope, elements, attrs){

      $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {

        // store scroll position for the current view
        if($route.current)
          cache[$route.current.loadedTemplateUrl + ':' + attrs.keepScrollPos] = [elements[0].scrollLeft, elements[0].scrollTop];              

      });

      $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){
        // if hash is specified explicitly, it trumps previously stored scroll position
        if($location.hash()){
          $anchorScroll();
          return;
        }

        // else get previous scroll position and apply it if it exists
        var pos = cache[$route.current.loadedTemplateUrl + ':' + attrs.keepScrollPos];
        if(!pos)
          return;

        $timeout(function(){                  
          elements[0].scrollLeft = pos[0];
          elements[0].scrollTop = pos[1];            
        }, 0);

      });

    }
  }

})
```

Use it like:

```
<div keep-scroll-pos="some-identifier"> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found another simple way to solve this issue:

```
var scrollValue = $(window).scrollTop();

$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function() {
    scrollValue = $(window).scrollTop();
});

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
    setTimeout(function() { $(window).scrollTop(scrollValue); }, 0);
});
```

Just put it in .run().

This way, setting timeout value to 0 it still works, but runs after the page is rendered (without timeout function it runs before the content (i.e. template or data loading) is rendered, making the function useless.

If you fetch data from some API, you can wrap the timeout in a function in $rootScope and run it after successful request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the scroll position on each route change.
Use this in your main AppController:

```
  $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function () {
    $anchorScroll();
  });
```

Or if you are using ui-route:

```
  $scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function () {
    $anchorScroll();
  });
```

For more infomation see [In AngularJS, how do I add a $watch on the URL hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002764/in-angularjs-how-do-i-add-a-watch-on-the-url-hash)

Answer (score 0):

this may solve your problem, it works for me
`$httpProvider.defaults.cache = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the other answers I wanted to remember more than just scrolls, namely `input` field `value`s.

Not only that, but a lot of them assumed

- you only wanted to remember one scrolling element (maybe you have panes or some other app-like display),
- you have `body` as your scrolling element (e.g. what if you're using [angular snap](http://jtrussell.github.io/angular-snap.js/)?),
- or your scrolling element isn't replaced by angular (i.e. it's outside the `ng-view`).

```html
<body> <!-- doesn't scroll -->
    <div snap-drawers>..</div>

    <div snap-content="" history="scrollTop"> <!-- the scrolling div-->
        <header>...</header>

        <div ng-view>
            <input name="email" history="val"> <!-- tag with value we want remembered -->

            <div history="scrollLeft" history-watch="scroll" id="evenHorizontalScroll"><!--
                custom value we want remembered.
                NB it must have an id to be identified after angular
                removes it from the DOM between views,
                and since it is not a recognised default we can tell my
                directive the jquery event function what to watch
            --></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I've written a[n unfortunately much longer] shared-scope directive that takes care of these problems.

```js
.directive('history', function($compile, $rootScope, $location) {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        replace : false,
        scope : false,

        controller : function($scope, $timeout) {
            //holds all the visited views
            var states = new Object();
            //the current view
            var state = null;
            //how many names have been generated where the element itself was used
            var generated = 0;

            //logs events if allowed
            function debug(from) {
                //comment this to watch it working
                //return;

                console.log('StateHistory: ' + from);
                if (from == 'went')
                    console.log(state);
            }

            //applies the remembered state
            function apply() {
                var element;
                //for each item remembered in the state
                for (var query in state) {
                    //use the element directly, otherwise search for it
                    (state[query].element || $(query))
                        //use the appropriate function
                        [state[query].property](
                            //and set the value
                            state[query].value
                        )
                    ;
                    debug('applying:' + query + ':' + state[query].value);
                }

                //start recording what the user does from this point onward
                $scope.ignore = false;
            }

            //generates a reference we can use as a map key
            $scope.generateRef = function() {
                return '' + (++generated);
            };

            //views changed
            $scope.went = function() {
                debug('went');

                //set the current state
                state = states[$location.path()];

                //if we dont remember the state of the page for this view
                if (!state)
                    //get recording!
                    state = states[$location.path()] = new Object();

                //apply the state after other directives
                //(like anchorScroll + autoscroll) have done their thing
                $timeout(apply);
            };

            //one of the elements we're watching has changed
            $scope.changed = function(name, element, property, useObject) {
                //if we're not meant to be watching right now
                //i.e. if the user isnt the one changing it
                if ($scope.ignore) {
                    debug('ignored');
                    return;
                }

                //if we havent recorded anything for this here yet
                if (!state[name]) {
                    //start recording
                    state[name] = {property:property};

                    //and remember to leave behind a reference if the name isn't
                    //good enough (was generated)
                    if (useObject)
                        state[name].element = element;
                }

                //use the requested function to pull the value
                state[name].value = element[property]();

                debug('changed:' + name + ':' + state[name].value);
            };

            //initial view
            $scope.went();

            //subsequent views
            $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', $scope.went);
            $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', $scope.went);

            $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
                debug('ignoring');
                $scope.ignore = true;
            });
        },

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //jquery event function name
            var watch = attrs.historyWatch;
            //if not set, use these defaults
            if (!watch) {
                switch (attrs.history) {
                case 'val':
                    watch = 'change';
                    break;
                case 'scrollTop':
                    watch = 'scroll';
                    break;
                default:
                    watch = attrs.history;
                }
            }

            //the css selector to re-find the element on view change
            var query = null;
            //the reference to the state remembered
            var name;

            //try using the id
            if (attrs.id)
                name = query = '#' + attrs.id;
            //try using the form name
            else if (attrs.name)
                name = query = '[name=' + attrs.name + ']';
            //otherwise we'll need to just reference the element directly
            //NB should only be used for elements not swapped out by angular on view change,
            //ie nothing within the view. Eg the view itself, to remember scrolling?
            else
                name = scope.generateRef();

            //jquery value function name
            var property = attrs.history;

            //watch this element from here on out
            element.on(watch, function() {
                scope.changed(name, element, property, !query);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using a custom solution in my project.

Step 1:  Obtain the position of the click on the list and save it in local storage.

```
var position = document.body.scrollTop;
localStorage.setItem("scrollPosition",position);
```

Step 2:In the detail view set a global variable backFromDetailView to true.

```
backFromDetailView = true;
```

Step 3:On returning from the detail view page to the list. All the content is reloaded from server again up to the scrolled position.

For this purpose bind a function in the html using the following line:

And the controller contains the function:

```
$scope.goto = function (){
    if(backFromDetailView){
         window.scrollTo(0, localStorage.getItem("scrollPosition"));
     }
}
```

Some disadvantages of this technique:

1. All the content including additional content is reloaded again.
2. In iOS, a black screen appear before scrolling to the appropriate
   position.

Answer (score 0):

Great solution by @br2000.

However unfortunately my page that I was scrolling back to, was still loading data from backend to a long list when the directive tried to restore the position.

So obviously it failed to restore the scroll position. I solved it by using `$interval` instead of `$timeout` and gave it 20 repetitions with `300ms timeout`. I stored the promise returned from `$interval` and then checked inside the `$interval` function if current position is now the same as stored position and if yes, I call a scope method that cancels the `$interval - $interval.cancel(promise).`

Additionally, initially my `pageYOffset` and `pageXOffset` were always 0, because `overflow-x: hidden` was applied to the root `div` in the `DOM`. I solved it by wrapping the root `div` inside another `div` on which I then placed this directive.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you that went with emp's answer, but were using angular ui-router >= version 1.0.0 (current 1.0.3), please see his directive rewritten, using ui-routers new transitions.

HTML

```
<div ui-view keep-scroll-pos></div>
```

Angular Directive

```
angular.module("app")
    .directive("keepScrollPos", function($transitions, $state, $window, $timeout, $location, $anchorScroll) {

        // cache scroll position of each state's templateUrl
        var scrollPosCache = {};

        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


                $transitions.onStart({ }, function( trans ) {

                    // store scroll position for the current view
                    if (trans.from().name) {
                        scrollPosCache[trans.from().templateUrl] = [ $window.pageXOffset, $window.pageYOffset ];
                    }

                    trans.promise.finally(function () {


                        // if hash is specified explicitly, it trumps previously stored scroll position
                        if ($location.hash()) {
                            $anchorScroll();

                        // else get previous scroll position; if none, scroll to the top of the page
                        } else {
                            var prevScrollPos = scrollPosCache[trans.to().templateUrl] || [ 0, 0 ];
                            $timeout(function() {
                                $window.scrollTo(prevScrollPos[0], prevScrollPos[1]);
                            }, 200);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
```