# Navigation history & scroll position

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, single-page-application

I am trying to figure out how to retain the state of views when navigating with the back or forward button in the browser. 
What would be a good practice to handle history data and scroll position in Angular?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you using routing? Have you tried a hash value or search param? What state specifically are you wanting to store?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I just found a similar question here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107531/retain-scroll-position-on-route-change-in-angularjs)