# HTML / Angular, how to return to specific place in long scroll on prior view

Tags: html, angularjs

I've a long list with a vert. scroll. Upon click of an item, it loads a 'detail' view. When I click 'back', however, the collection view appears again from the top. I want to return to the specific scroll level(?) the user had when they clicked 'details'.

Comment: How does your "collection -> item" code look like? Also is the collection paginated or is it fixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107531/retain-scroll-position-on-route-change-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Without having much details in your question, I think the easiest way to do this is using the history back() method. It is described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp) on w3schools.com, including an example.