# AngularJs Browser Back Button: Go Back to Previous Spot on Page

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular for a single page application.  Sometimes I have a longer list of items.  When the user scrolls down the page and clicks on the item, they go to a detailed view for that item.  If they hit the back button on the browser angular takes them back to the list, but it goes back to the top of the list.

Normally on a simple HTML page, if you scroll down a page, and click on a link and go to another page if you hit the back button on the browser, it takes you right back to the scroll location where you were on that page.  This is very helpful if you're going through a list of items.

Is there a way to have Angular mimic that behavior so that using the back button will take the user back to the list and the same scroll location?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retain scroll position on route change in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107531/retain-scroll-position-on-route-change-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make use of the HTML history API such as `window.history.pushState()` and `window.history.popState()`. It also sounds like you want to use browser scrolling.

A quick google search found me [this documentation about $location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location) 
and [this documentation about scrolling](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24anchorScroll) from the AngularJS docs.

I don't know how to do this in AngularJS, but in jQuery you can use `pushState()` to add a specific url to the browser history (that might be a # on your same page) and then you can add a `popState()` handler that will do something other than refresh the page when the user clicks the back button.

For example

```
$(document).on('load',function(){
 window.history.replaceState({element: {positionY: 0}},"load",location.pathname);
});

$(mylink).click(function(evt){
 // something like: window.history.pushState(evt.target);
});

// this occurs when the user clicks the back button
$(document).on("popstate", function(evt) {
 evt.preventDefault(); // prevents page refresh
 var state = evt.originalEvent.state;
 window.scrollTo(0,state.element.positionY);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I do have angular in HTML5 mode, but the back button will always bring the user back to the top of the page, even if they had scrolled down.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Angular uses the history API. The problem is not in going back and forth. It's about not losing the location in the list page.

Comment: @Frank My suggestion would be to search for more information on the history API and on browser scrolling in javascript. You can use the history API to get information about what they click on before they hit the back button (or if they didn't click on anything, you can actually do `replaceState()` on page load so that when they hit the back button you know that the previous thing they looked at was just the plain page).

Comment: Thanks, I see there might already be an answer here:  [Retain Scroll Position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107531/retain-scroll-position-on-route-change-in-angularjs)