# In AngularJS, how do I add a $watch on the URL hash?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angular, how can I add a watch that is fired when the hash is updated, either by my application, or when the browser updates the URL from either the URL bar or the back/forward buttons?

Comment: Not sure about the hash itself, but the way I always check for that is `$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {});`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`$scope.$watch` accepts function as the first argument, so you can do this:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return location.hash
}, function (value) {
    // do stuff
});
```

But I would recommend [using events](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope), such as `$routeChangeSuccess` for [default router](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider):

```
$scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function () {})
```

or `$stateChangeSuccess` for [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

```
$scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function () {})
```

Comment: `$routeChangeSuccess` doesn't fire when only the hash changes.

Comment: The scope.watch suggestion to check for hash changes works really well (and of course still worked with ngNewRouter too as it's not router dependant).

Comment: The $scope.$watch() doesn't fire when I changed the url hash

Comment: @KevinBeal, watch both success and `$routeChangeError`, but obviously this wont work if you're using a [non-default scheme](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) (in which case use the equivalent/s for that library)

Answer (score 20):

[$locationChangeSuccess](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#$locationChangeSuccess) could be better.

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl){
    // TODO What you want on the event.
});
```

Comment: @PhamHuyAnh it is working for me, and I am just using Angular 1.2.21 in the project. Make sure you inject `$location`.  If you don't, it won't work for hash change event observing

Comment: I'm also on 1.2.x and this worked precisely for a hash change. Less overhead than a $watch

Answer (score 8):

This works too if you're okay with not using the angular $watch.
Basically, you watch **'hashchange'** windows event. whatever angularJS does is a wrapper around this. For example,

```
$($window).bind('hashchange', function () {

    // Do what you need to do here like... getting imageId from #
    var currentImageId = $location.search().imageId;

});
```

Comment: I guess there is a mistake in $window. Also it is not crossbrowser solution.

Comment: This works outside of the angular digest logic, so you have to add a `$scope.$apply()` in the callback (if any models are changed). If that doesn't matter for your purposes, then this is a good solution.

Comment: This is all kinds of bad due to mixing jQ and Angular and not "the Angular way" since none of the Angular wrapping and digest is included in this approach. The above answers give solid examples of how to do this correctly in Angular.

Comment: That worked for me when trying to inject js functions to an existing Angular online webapp for styling purposes in Electron.

Answer (score 1):

location.hash can be updated internally by angular or externally by the user or the browser (click link in bookmarks). If it is updated internally angular runs a $scope.$apply(). If an external event updates location.hash $watch does only fire UNTIL AFTER the next $scope.$apply(), e.g. a user pushes a button within your app.

If you wish to use a $watch, add an additional event listener to "hashchange" to call $apply, or add all functionality to the native DOM listener AND do not forget to call $apply(), as this is an external call.

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(){ $scope.$apply(); }, false);
```

OR ...

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(){ me._locationHashChanged(); $scope.$apply(); }, false);
```