# Watching external variable in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've written a small JS library for Serial communication in a Chrome app, and it works fine on its own. However, we're running into a problem in integration with Angular: I don't have a way to watch a property of the serial object outside the controller from inside, and I have not been able to find a workaround. Ideally, there's a solution that isn't too computationally expensive, bu at this point, I am not ruling out some way to convert the entire library to a more Angular-friendly format. However, in this situation I'm not sure whether it should go in a service or some other format. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just borrowed the idea from here: [In AngularJS, how do I add a $watch on the URL hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002764/in-angularjs-how-do-i-add-a-watch-on-the-url-hash)

$scope.$watch accepts function as the first argument, so you can do this:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return mylib.myproperty
}, function (value) {
    // do stuff
});
```

UPDATE:
As noted in the comments, when mylib.myproperty changes the controller won't know about it until the next digest cicle. Since mylib is not angular-enabled you need to use a plain javascript callback mechanism:

```
mylib.on_myproperty_change(function(){
    $scope.$digest(); // this will cause the $watch to be re-evaluated
});
```

But since now you already have a `mylib.on_myproperty_change` you don't really need to `$watch` anything, so you can delete the watch and just

```
mylib.on_myproperty_change(function(){
    //do the stuff that you did in the the $watch
    $scope.$digest(); 
});
```

Comment: +1; although doesn't this add a "global dependency' to the controller, which is universally considered a bad thing from a unit testing perspective?

Comment: The callback will only be called when something causes a digest cycle. If the user/app is not interacting with the angular part of the app and changes `mylib.myproperty`, you won't be notified.

Comment: As @Sylvain said, my concern with this is that I would like dynamic updates without user interaction. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: You guys are right. I think there's a good way to solve this problem though. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @TonyLâmpada @Sylvain Can someone elaborate on the answer above?  what exactly is `on_myproperty_change` ?  I too have an global object I need to track changes for inside a controller and am not able to get $watch to evaluate things when the global obj.property is changed.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own custom library as an Angular service:

```
myAngularApp.service('MyCustomLib', function(){
    return myCustomLibInstance;
    }]
);
```

Then you can pass it into a controller and save it to the local scope:

```
function MyCtrl($scope,MyCustomLib) {
  var myCustomLib = MyCustomLib;
```

And now you have access to your custom library from inside the controller and you can set up a watch, as @tony  had suggested in his answer:

```
$scope.$watch(
function () { 
  return myCustomLib.property 
}, 
function (newValue, oldValue) { 
 // do stuff 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The method I use to kick off a digest cycle is `$timeout(function () {})`.

`$scope.$digest()` will throw an error if there is already an existing digest cycle running.

I have it as

```
// From my controller
externalService.setOnChangeCallback(function () { $timeout(function () {}) });

// in my service
// on change event
this.onChangeCallBack();
```

`$scope.$watch` didn't reliably run for me. Sometimes the watched value was re-evaluated, sometimes it was not.