# AngularJS required input, set with code, invalid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a text input that is set to `required`. The field is a date range picker. When the code for the date range picker enters the text, angular is not recognizing the input as being filled. It is still casing a validation error saying the field is required. Any ideas? I tried `$setValidity('required',true);` No luck there.

I am using this date range picker: [Link](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options)

Here's the code. First on the html side, my input:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="daterange" id="daterange" ng-model="daterange" placeholder="Pick A Date"/>
```

Then on the javascript side I setup the input as a daterange picker

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    "autoApply": true,
    "autoUpdateInput": false
});

$('#daterange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    $('#daterange').val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
});

$('#daterange').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    $('#daterange').val('');
});
```

I am using some angular on the HTML side to show all my form errors

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, errors) in requestForm.$error track by $index"> <strong>{{ key }}</strong> errors
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="e in errors">{{ e.$name }} has an error: <strong>{{ key }}</strong>.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

If I manually type in the field it will validate. But using the date range picker it does not.

Comment: are you using ui-bootstrap or plain html control?

Comment: Incomplete information, share your html code!

Comment: yes, using bootstrap

Comment: I think you will have to use $watch to let angular know that scope has been changed. Since you are updating value of element with jQuery, angular will not be aware of this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002956/watching-external-variable-in-angularjs and https://henriquat.re/directives/advanced-directives-combining-angular-with-existing-components-and-jquery/angularAndJquery.html

Comment: are you using jquery and angulr together ?

Comment: Yes, using angular and jQuery. I tried using both `$digest()` and `$apply()` to get angular to realize the field was update. But no luck. I tried it these within the daterange on apply function so that I didn't have to worry about picking up the change with a `$watch`. Also tried manually setting `$setDirty()` but that's not doing the trick either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally figured this out. The issue is that the daterange picker wasn't setting the value the angular way. It was doing it with jQuery:

```
$('#daterange').val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

By using the same call back from daterange picker but using the angular way to set the value:

```
$scope.daterange = (picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

the validator picks up on it. Thanks for the help everyone