# Links with different hash values not reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, hash

I have a number of links in my navigation menu that have the same absolute path but unique hash values. These hash values are used by angularjs for setting filters on the page. One of the features of this is that on page load, the hash is read and used to display/hide items on the page.

The problem is that when I'm on one of these pages, when I click a link that has a different hash (i.e. a clicking on the link for the product page with a different filter from the main navigation, rather than using the filters on the page), the url changes, but the page doesn't reload.

For example, if I'm on `mysite.com/products#?filters=Green` and I go to the navigation menu and click on the "Products > Red" link, which is `mysite.com/products#?filters=Red`, the url updates but my page doesn't reload, so the display on my page doesn't actually change, because that depends on the onload function that reads the url.

How can I make these urls reload the page when the path is the same but the hash is different?

Comment: What about listening to hashChange event and updating your filters? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002764/in-angularjs-how-do-i-add-a-watch-on-the-url-hash.

Comment: I assume you listen `windows.onhashchange` and you load your content on attached listener triggered ?

Comment: did you include `<base href="/" />` in your `html`?