# $state.go is not changing the Url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, browser-history, pushstate

I am using, Angular.js 1.3, with ui-router.
I have 3 pages, page1.html, page2.html, page3.html.

When user click on page1, page2 will open, but I want to save the scroll state of page 1, where user was before clicking, so that after clicking on back button he lands on same scroll state.

To solve this I opened the page2.html over the page1.html, in iframe, and giving it absolute position to display over the page1.html, and I am using the:

`history.pushState({}, '', '/page2.html');`

to change the url. This implementation working fine.

Now when user click on link on page2.html, it should open the page3.html, like a normal link, for which I used :

```
$state.go("page3")
```

The problem is now the state chages, and page3.html loads, but url is still the /page2.html, url is not changing.

I even tried:

```
history.pushState({}, '', '/page3.html');
```

Still url is not changing. Anyone know why it's happening.

Comment: I am not sure this will work. but I guess you are in `Iframe` that is why its not changing this url. can you try `eval` when you are in page2. may be `parent.eval($state.go("page3"))` something like this.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle?

Comment: Sorry I can't post it on jsfiddle. But yeah I can understand that the link is in iframe, that's why it is not changing url (probably). But the js code running fine, history.pushState is running (Js source debugger), but it has no effect on url. Will dig more about iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the solution you are trying to implement is very creative, I would really choose another direction.

You've got various option, all of which rely on caching the scroll position somewhere. For example:

```
var scrollTopData = {};

function changeState (toState) {
    var currentStateName = $state.current.name;
    scrollTopData[currentStateName] = window.scrollY;
    $state.go(toState);
}
```

Then the question remains what to do with the scroll position you have cached. `$state.go` returns a promise, so a solution would be:

```
var scrollTopData = {};

function changeState (toState) {
    var currentStateName = $state.current.name;
    scrollTopData[currentStateName] = window.scrollY;

    $state.go(toState).then(function () {
        if (toState in scrollTopData) {
            window.scrollTo(0, scrollTopData[toState]);
        }
    });
}
```

Depending on your implementation, you could also use the answer of [asgoth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14110132/5671829):

> I haven't used it before, but angular has a [$anchorScroll](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24anchorScroll) service. As to reloading the data, you could cache it using [$cacheFactory](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24cacheFactory), or store the data on a higher scope.

Another solution would be to use a [stateChangeEvent](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events). For example:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        // Do magic
    }
);
```

My advice would be to use the promise returned by `$state.go`.

Comment: Yeah thanks for this info. But my project involves infinite scroll: on first load, API gives 1st 20 product, then on scroll next 20 comes, so if user has scrolled down to 3rd times and click on item, then hit back button, the API gets called from starting, so saving scroll point is not useful, since the data is not available. My current solution shows the clicked page on top, thus removing it on popstate saves the API hit again and it remains at the same position as before.

Comment: Well that information would have come in handy before answering :) Anyway, the concept remains the same, with an addition: you could put the page number that you're using when you load more articles into the hashed path. When the infinite scrolling page is loaded, check the page number, load everything up to that and scroll the window to the last known scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have a change in url if you change the default behavior of angular. The part in url after hash changes automatically. You do not have changing urls because you force the browser to /somepage.html

try some thing like /#somepage.html

note the hash(#) added here.